# Updating a scheduled task with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I wanted to know if it was possible to use PowerShell to modify the scheduled task, and change the security setting from "Run whether user is logged or not" to "Run only when user is logged on”.

I have to do it in an automated way to repair a scheduled task on several hundred machines.

I looked at the config file of the scheduled tasks (%systemroot%\System32\Tasks) and compared the file with the 2 versions of the security setting, but I found no differences.

I also looked at the regedit, but the registers of the scheduled tasks are incomprehensible for me.

The commands/procedures that ChatGPT advised me did not work either.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

- Use Get-ScheduledTask and store it in a variable to store the definition of the task: `$task = Get-ScheduledTask TaskName`
- Set the Principal value of that output to the interactive users group: `$task.Principal.UserID = $null; $task.Principal.GroupID = "S-1-5-4"` *Thanks to **kconsiglio** for the addition here!
- Pipe `task` to Set-ScheduledTask to remove the Principal. This will then set the task to run under the context of the currently logged on user if they are logged in: `$task | Set-ScheduledTask`

Comment: instead of doing `$task.Principal = $null`. You could also do this:
`$task.Principal.UserId = $Null` set userid to null. Then set the GroupId to the interactive users group. `$task.Principal.GroupId = "S-1-5-4"` . Then the last command would be the same. In this way it should work whether or not a user is currently logged in or not and still change the setting to "Run only when the user is logged in"

Comment: Great addition, I'll edit my answer to say that

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but not exactly the way I intend.

I was able to come up with something that does what I want, by changing the LogonType of the Principal section, I was then able to change the security parramtter of the scheduled task from "Run whether user is logged or not" to "Run only when user is logged on”.

```powershell
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskName" -TaskPath "TaskPath" 
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "UserId" -LogonType Interactive 
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName -TaskName "TaskName" -TaskPath "TaskPath" -Principal $principal
```